# Make reference table data read-only - EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, fluent, ef-core-2.0

I have a table (`Commodity`) which has a one-to-one relationship with another table (`CommodityMaterial`), in my GET endpoint the Commodity returns it's own columns and also the columns (and values) of the referenced table which works perfectly. However, in the POST operation of the endpoint, a user should not be able to POST data of the reference table (`CommodityMaterial`), how can this be achieved? I used to disable this by using a DataContract, however, because I need the columns for my GET operator, this is not an option.

I already tried, following this post: https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/11/07/efcorefields/, removing the SET on the reference table and making a backing field but this does not seem to work (error that the backing field is read-only).

I also tried setting the SET to protected, but this is not working.

So the question is, how to make the reference table read-only (only available for my GET endpoint and not my POST endpoint).

The Commodity POCO class:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Commodity
    {
        public Commodity()
        {

        }

        public Commodity(CommodityMaterial commodityMaterial)
        {
            CommodityMaterial = commodityMaterial;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public long CommodityID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public long CommodityMaterialID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public decimal? SpecficWeight { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public CommodityMaterial CommodityMaterial { get; }
    }
```

Fluent part:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Commodity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.CommodityID)
                    .HasColumnName("CommodityID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                entity.Property(e => e.CommodityMaterialID)
                    .HasColumnName("CommodityMaterialID");

                entity.Property(e => e.SpecficWeight)
                    .HasColumnName("SpecficWeight")
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");

                entity.HasOne(a => a.CommodityMaterial)
                    .WithOne(b => b.Commodity)
                    .HasForeignKey<Commodity>(b => b.CommodityMaterialID);

            });
```

Comment: It's possible to setup EF Core to use a backing field for a navigation property (although not so straight forward as for primitive properties as in the link). However you should not be mixing EF (storage) models with domain / business logic or DTO / View models. Whatever you do at the class level, I don't see how you can prevent the client from GET-ting an object with `CommodityMaterial` populated and simply POST-ing it back. Consider the advice from Chris Prat's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters your action accepts should represent what your action does/is allowed to do. If a client should not be able to update a related entity, then the class you bind the request body to, should not have that entity available. Use a view model, essentially:

```
public class CommodityRequest
{
    // all properties you want editable
    // exclude `CommodityMaterial` obviously
}
```

Then:

```
public IActionResult Update(CommodityRequest model)
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually already used some ViewModels for other tables but somehow I didn't think of it for this situation..